# User controlled dark or light mode script is not doing anything when I clicked on the switch buttons

Tags: javascript

Peace,

I am trying to implement dark, system and light mode colour scheme switcher on my website.

Base on the user's system settings, I got the dark or light scheme working with CSS and HTML. Currently, it will automatically work base on the user's system scheme. And you can also use Firefox dev tool to switch from light to dark mode.

I have already implemented the switch buttons in the HTML and by default the colour scheme is set to system using `aria-pressed="true"` attribute on that button.

```
  <div class="cp-theme-switcher" role="group" title="Select a color scheme">
    <button data-color-scheme="dark" class="cp-theme-switcher__button cp-theme-switcher__button--dark" type="button" aria-pressed="false" title="Dark color scheme">
        <span class="ut-visually-hidden">Dark color scheme</span>
    </button>
  
    <button data-color-scheme="system" class="cp-theme-switcher__button cp-theme-switcher__button--system" type="button" aria-pressed="true" title="System color scheme">
        <span class="ut-visually-hidden">System color scheme</span>
    </button>
  
    <button data-color-scheme="light" class="cp-theme-switcher__button  cp-theme-switcher__button--light" type="button" aria-pressed="false" title="Light color scheme">
      <span class="ut-visually-hidden">Light color scheme</span>
    </button>
  </div>
```

And in the CSS, I use that attribute to also show the right icon mode to the user like so:

```
.cp-theme-switcher__button[aria-pressed="true"] {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

The HTML and CSS is okay, But I have a problem with the script, If I clicked on the other switch buttons (light or dark) nothings happens and I don't know why that is happening.

[dark and light mode figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3bPsY.png)

Here are the codes

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Color Scheme</title>

</head>
<body>

  <div class="cp-theme-switcher" role="group" title="Select a color scheme">
    <button data-color-scheme="dark" class="cp-theme-switcher__button cp-theme-switcher__button--dark" type="button" aria-pressed="false" title="Dark color scheme">
        <svg 
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
            width="16" 
            height="16" 
            class="ob-icon cp-theme-switcher__icon" 
            viewBox="0 0 16 16"
            focusable="false"
            aria-hidden="true"
        >
            <path d="M6 .278a.768.768 0 0 1 .08.858 7.208 7.208 0 0 0-.878 3.46c0 4.021 3.278 7.277 7.318 7.277.527 0 1.04-.055 1.533-.16a.787.787 0 0 1 .81.316.733.733 0 0 1-.031.893A8.349 8.349 0 0 1 8.344 16C3.734 16 0 12.286 0 7.71 0 4.266 2.114 1.312 5.124.06A.752.752 0 0 1 6 .278zM4.858 1.311A7.269 7.269 0 0 0 1.025 7.71c0 4.02 3.279 7.276 7.319 7.276a7.316 7.316 0 0 0 5.205-2.162c-.337.042-.68.063-1.029.063-4.61 0-8.343-3.714-8.343-8.29 0-1.167.242-2.278.681-3.286z"/>
        </svg>
        
        <span class="ut-visually-hidden">Dark color scheme</span>
    </button>
  
    <button data-color-scheme="system" class="cp-theme-switcher__button cp-theme-switcher__button--system" type="button" aria-pressed="true" title="System color scheme">
      <svg 
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
      width="16" 
      height="16" 
      class="ob-icon cp-theme-switcher__icon" 
      viewBox="0 0 16 16"
      focusable="false"
      aria-hidden="true"
  >
      <path d="M3.204 5h9.592L8 10.481 3.204 5zm-.753.659 4.796 5.48a1 1 0 0 0 1.506 0l4.796-5.48c.566-.647.106-1.659-.753-1.659H3.204a1 1 0 0 0-.753 1.659z"/>
  </svg>
        
        <span class="ut-visually-hidden">System color scheme</span>
    </button>
  
    <button data-color-scheme="light" class="cp-theme-switcher__button  cp-theme-switcher__button--light" type="button" aria-pressed="false" title="Light color scheme">
      <svg 
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
      width="16" 
      height="16" 
      class="ob-icon cp-theme-switcher__icon"
      viewBox="0 0 16 16"
      focusable="false"
      aria-hidden="true"
      >
          <path d="M8 11a3 3 0 1 1 0-6 3 3 0 0 1 0 6zm0 1a4 4 0 1 0 0-8 4 4 0 0 0 0 8zM8 0a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v2a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0v-2A.5.5 0 0 1 8 0zm0 13a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v2a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0v-2A.5.5 0 0 1 8 13zm8-5a.5.5 0 0 1-.5.5h-2a.5.5 0 0 1 0-1h2a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5zM3 8a.5.5 0 0 1-.5.5h-2a.5.5 0 0 1 0-1h2A.5.5 0 0 1 3 8zm10.657-5.657a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .707l-1.414 1.415a.5.5 0 1 1-.707-.708l1.414-1.414a.5.5 0 0 1 .707 0zm-9.193 9.193a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .707L3.05 13.657a.5.5 0 0 1-.707-.707l1.414-1.414a.5.5 0 0 1 .707 0zm9.193 2.121a.5.5 0 0 1-.707 0l-1.414-1.414a.5.5 0 0 1 .707-.707l1.414 1.414a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .707zM4.464 4.465a.5.5 0 0 1-.707 0L2.343 3.05a.5.5 0 1 1 .707-.707l1.414 1.414a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .708z"/>
      </svg>
        
      <span class="ut-visually-hidden">Light color scheme</span>
    </button>
  </div>

    <h1>
     How to handle color scheme from default system to user controlled dark or light mode 
    </h1>

    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nostrum consequuntur veniam modi optio, nulla suscipit molestiae aut. Alias suscipit porro obcaecati veritatis maiores optio doloribus est non! Exercitationem, consectetur ullam.
    </p>

    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Numquam, odit accusantium vel nemo, atque quisquam asperiores, aliquam maiores amet aperiam reprehenderit? Quo illum perspiciatis, minus quibusdam adipisci provident ex ratione!
    </p>
  
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
  <style>


:root {
  --ref-black: #000000;
  --ref-white:#ffffff;

  color-scheme: light dark;
}


@media (prefers-color-scheme: light) {
  :root {
    --canvas: var(--ref-white);
    --canvas-text: var(--ref-black);
    --button-color: var(--ref-black);
  }
}

@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
  :root {
    --canvas: var(--ref-black);
    --canvas-text: var(--ref-white);
    --button-color: var(--ref-white);
  }
}


body {
  margin: 76px;
}
.cp-theme-switcher {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 72px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  border: 2px solid var(--button-color);

  
}

.cp-theme-switcher:hover {
  border-color: var(--button-color);
}


.cp-theme-switcher__button {
  position: absolute;
  border: none;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 2px solid var(--button-color);
  width: 32px;
 height: 32px;
 display: flex;

align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  appearance: none;
  opacity: 0;

  
}


.cp-theme-switcher__button[aria-pressed="true"] {
    opacity: 1;
}


.cp-theme-switcher__icon {
 width: 16px;
 height: 16px;
}


  .cp-theme-switcher__button--dark {
    left: -2px;
  }
  
  .cp-theme-switcher__button--system {
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    z-index: 10;
    
  }
  
  .cp-theme-switcher__button--light {
    right: -2px;
  }

  .ut-visually-hidden {
  position: absolute !important;
  overflow: hidden !important;
  width: 1px !important;
  height: 1px !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
  border: 0 !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
  clip: rect(0 0 0 0) !important;
  clip-path: inset(50%) !important;
  white-space: nowrap !important;
}
  </style>
```

JS

```
<script>
// scheme picker
(() => {

const  colorSchemeSwitchers = document.querySelectorAll('[data-color-scheme]')

function removeColorScheme () {
  localStorage.removeItem('color-scheme')
}

function saveColorScheme (colorScheme) {
  if (colorScheme === 'system') {
    removeColorScheme()
    return
  }

  localStorage.setItem('color-scheme', colorScheme)
}

function applyColorScheme () {
  const localStorageColorScheme = localStorage.getItem('color-scheme');
  const colorScheme = localStorageColorScheme || null

  if (colorScheme) {
    document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-color-scheme', colorScheme)
  }
}

function colorSchemeSwitcherHandler () {
  colorSchemeSwitchers.forEach((colorSchemeSwitcher) => {
    const colorScheme = colorSchemeSwitcher.getAttribute('data-color-scheme')

    // Cast the state as a boolean
    let pressed = colorSchemeSwitcher.getAttribute('aria-pressed') === false

    if (colorScheme === localStorage.getItem('color-scheme')) {
      // flip the state 
      pressed.setAttribute('aria-pressed', !pressed)
    }

    colorSchemeSwitcher.addEventListener('change', () => {
      if (colorScheme !== 'system') {
        saveColorScheme(colorScheme)
        applyColorScheme(colorScheme)
      } else {
        removeColorScheme()
        document.documentElement.removeAttribute('data-color-scheme')
      }
    })
  })

  applyColorScheme()
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  colorSchemeSwitcherHandler()
  applyColorScheme()
})


})();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are listening for the wrong event on the switcher buttons. Currently, you are listening on the [`change` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event), which is:

> […] fired for `<input>`, `<select>`, and `<textarea>` elements when an alteration to the element's value is committed by the user.

You are using `<button>` elements, and so they will never fire a `change` event. You can look at changing the event to [`click`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/click_event), and as it sounds, your event listener would fire when the button is clicked:

```js
    colorSchemeSwitcher.addEventListener('click', () => {
      if (colorScheme !== 'system') {
        saveColorScheme(colorScheme)
        applyColorScheme(colorScheme)
      } else {
        removeColorScheme()
        document.documentElement.removeAttribute('data-color-scheme')
      }
    })
```